# Insetting Csv into sql database and removing special character

Tags: sql, rdbms

sample data

```
10001|23|1|"abcd"|4|"A"<</EOR>>
```

how to remove these <> (unwanted parameter from string) while inserting into sql from csv tried each and every row delimeters but not getting it /n all used so please help me out?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? Which tool do you use to import the CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

use `replace`;

```
select replace('10001|23|1|"abcd"|4|"A"<>', '<>', '') from dual;
```

output:

```
10001|23|1|"abcd"|4|"A"
```

Comment: please tag your RDBMS